# Unit testing a RestAPI client that doesn't implement a protocol

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm new to developing code and writing unit tests.

I need to write a unit test for a `getData(url)` method that would return `nil` if the data coming from another call within the function is `nil`

Sample code

```
func getData(url: URL) -> string? {
  guard let jsonData = self.get(url) else {
    return nil
  }
  .....
}
```

Here how would I make the test go to return nil part

- Check if the class is implementing any protocols, but its not. So I think I cannot use mocking/stubbing where I could say return `nil` for `get(url)` call

Comment: What is your get func ? If you pass an invalid url, it should probably fail and thus you would get a nil.

Comment: wow, that simple logic worked. Thanks @claude31